# Set dynamic hoverlabel background color in R plotly scattergl

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

The dynamic hoverlabel background color in R plotly does not seem to work when using `scattergl` instead of `scatter` as depicted in the example below.

Works as intended with `type = "scatter"`:

```r
library(plotly)

X <- data.frame(x = 1:6,
                y = 1:6,
                z  = 1:6)

plot_ly(data = X, x = ~x, y = ~y,
        type = "scatter", mode = "markers",
        marker = list(color = ~x, 
                      colorscale = list(c(0, .5, 1), c('#0d71db', "#dbc00d", "#db220d"))))
```

[image]

The hoverlabel background color becomes black for all data points with `type = "scattergl"`:

```r
plot_ly(data = X, x = ~x, y = ~y,
        type = "scattergl", mode = "markers",
        marker = list(color = ~x, 
                      colorscale = list(c(0, .5, 1), c('#0d71db', "#dbc00d", "#db220d"))))
```

[image]

I guess a solution could be to pass the same color array used in `colorscale` to the [bgcolor](https://plotly.com/r/reference/scattergl/#scattergl-hoverlabel-bgcolor) argument via `hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = ???)`. However I have no idea how to do so.

---

**Edit**
Tried this based on @Quinten's answer, without success. As can be seen the colors are the default plot_ly colors and do not correspond to what is specified in `cols`.

```r
library(plotly)

n <- 5000
X <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100, n, replace = TRUE),
                y = sample(1:100, n, replace = TRUE),
                z = sample(1:500, n, replace = TRUE))

length_unique_vals <- length(unique(X$z))
cols <- colorRampPalette(c('#0d71db', "#dbc00d", "#db220d"))(length_unique_vals)
cols <- cols[factor(X$z)]

plot_ly(data = X, x = ~x, y = ~y,
        type = "scattergl", mode = "markers",
        marker = list(color = ~z,
                      colorscale = cols,
                      colorbar = list(title = "Colorbar")),
        hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = cols)) %>% 
  toWebGL()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a vector of 6 different colors using `RColorBrewer`. These colors you assign to the `color` of your `marker` and to the `bgcolor` of your `hoverlabel` which will show the right color. You can use the following code:

```
library(plotly)

X <- data.frame(x = 1:6,
                y = 1:6,
                z  = 1:6)

library(RColorBrewer)
cols <- brewer.pal(n = 6, name = "Set3")

plot_ly(data = X, x = ~x, y = ~y,
        type = "scattergl", mode = "markers",
        marker = list(color = cols), 
        hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = cols))
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see from the plot, the label is the same color as the marker.

Comment: Nice! However, it is really important for me to be able to reproduce the same specific `colorscale` I am using in my example. Not sure I will be able to find it using `RColorBrewer`. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @mat, Do you know which colors you have between the defined colors of your `colorscale`. If so, then it is easy for you to make your own vector of colors. You don't need the `RColorBrewer`, it was just as an example.

Comment: Came up with a generalized answer build on your answer as my dataset is in fact more complex than the one I used as example.

Comment: I realize it is not what I was looking for, I do need to use the argument `colorscale` because I want to have a colorbar as a legend. If I pass a color array to `colorscale` is stops working.

Comment: Is it possible to supply a vector/list of colours, rather than a palette? For example, `hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = c('red', 'green', 'blue'))`. A single colour works in this way (using `ggplotly()`), but not multiple colours. I have 6 geoms in the original `ggplot`, but supplying anywhere from 2-6 colours doesn't work.

Comment: @hugh-allan, Yes it is possible, but you should take in account the amount of points you have. If you explicitly give the points a color like you mentioned above, it should work.